# Uso optimo para comparar un array

Tags: php, laravel

Buen dia, tengo dos variables que lleno con una respuesta de la api independiente asi:

```
$email1 = "infra@gmail.com"
$email2 = "lib@gmail.com"
```

y un array que viene del front-end

```
$array= [
    "infra@gmail.com.co",
    "lib@gmail.com.co",
    "lib@gmail.com.co",
    "infra@gmail.com.co"
]
```

Necesito validar cuantas veces existe cada correo en el array para lo cual utilice el siguiente código:

```
    $contadorEmail1 = 0;
    $contadorEmail2 = 0;
    foreach ($array as $response) {
     switch ($response) {
      case $email1:
       $contadorEmail1 += 1;
       break;
      case $email2:
       $contadorEmail2 += 1;
       break;
     }
    }
```

Me funciona pero quiero saber si no existe una manera mas optima de realizar el conteo, intente con `array_map()` pero no logre avanzar muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función **[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php)** sería lo más óptimo. Podrías crear una función que reciba como argumento un array y una cadena indicando el correo, y que devuelva el número de veces que aparece dicho correo en el array pasado.

Ejemplo:

```
function cuantasVecesApareceEsteCorreo($correo, $array)
{
    // Obtiene una lista donde los índices son los correos
    // y los valores indican el número de veces que existen
    $lista = array_count_values($array);
    // Si el correo indicado existe en la lista devuelve el
    // número de veces que aparece, caso contrario devuelve 0
    return $lista[$correo] ?? 0;
}
```

En tu caso

```
$array = [
    "infra@gmail.com.co",
    "lib@gmail.com.co",
    "lib@gmail.com.co",
    "infra@gmail.com.co"
];

$email1 = "infra@gmail.com.co";
$email2 = "lib@gmail.com.co";
$email3 = "otro@gmail.com";

$vecesQueApareceEmail1 = cuantasVecesApareceEsteCorreo($email1, $array); // Devuelve 2
$vecesQueApareceEmail2 = cuantasVecesApareceEsteCorreo($email2, $array); // Devuelve 2
$vecesQueApareceEmail3 = cuantasVecesApareceEsteCorreo($email3, $array); // Devuelve 0
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto además que la función la voy a reutilizar en otra parte del proyecto con otra información Gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

Puedes obtener el número de ocurrencias utilizando array_count_values:

```
$email1 = "email@email.com";
$array = array("email@email.com", "email2@email.com", "email@email.com", "email3@email.com", "email@email.com");
$count = array_count_values($array);
echo($count);
```

Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar un `array_reduce`, e inicializarlo con valores en 0 para los contadores `cont1` y `cont2`.

```
$array= [
    "infra@gmail.com.co",
    "lib@gmail.com.co",
    "lib@gmail.com.co",
    "infra@gmail.com.co"
];

$email1 = "infra@gmail.com.co";
$email2 = "lib@gmail.com.co";

$result = array_reduce($array, function($acc, $e) use($email1, $email2) {
    if($e === $email1) $acc["cont1"]++;
    if($e === $email2) $acc["cont2"]++;
    return $acc;
}, ["cont1" => 0, "cont2" => 0]);

var_dump($result);

//array(2) {
//  ["cont1"]=>
//  int(2)
//  ["cont2"]=>
//  int(2)
//}
```